# unable to update gems on mac osx - Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

```
Jon-MacBook-Pro:rubygems-1.3.7 jon$ sudo gem install rails
Password:
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    SocketError: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (http://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport-2.3.8.gem)
```

Comment: Put four spaces before each line for this kind of text.

Comment: Is this question unhelpful because it only applies some of the time? Shouldn't rubygems provide a more informative error message?

Comment: It's almost a year and still the same problem and no answers :-(

Comment: @lud0h there is an answer. When that error appears rubygems is down or unreachable from your connection.

Answer (score 4):

rubygems.org is down right now. Try again later.